# telegram bot insert into database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i need to insert some data to database which is $user_id and $username

i used telegram method to define them :

```
$user_id = $message->from->id;
$username = $message->from->username;
```

them made this code :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($text == '/start' and strpos($check, '"status":"left"') == TRUE){
    if($rowcount = 0){
        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO 
                                users (id,username,points) 
                                VALUES ('$user_id','$username','0')");
    }
    bot('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
        'text'=>'a text',
        'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
        'inline_keyboard'=>[
            [['text'=>'my text','url'=>'my link']]
        ]
        ])
    ]);
}
```

the problem is that the query doesn't insert anything to the table, I checked $rowcount and it returns a valid value.

also checked $username and $user_id methods.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Look at the manual for mysqli and find out how to check that the connection was actually made correctly

Comment: Also, be warned that your code is open for SQL injection

Comment: You may wanna look into prepared statements here, its wide open for sql injection

Answer (score 4):

check your comparison 
`if($rowcount = 0){`
use double equal `==`

Answer (score -1):

In my situation the reason for not inserting rows in database was that db user wasn't associated with the database.

Also maybe

`strpos($check, '"status":"left"') === TRUE)`

Comment: What does that mean? How did you solve the problem?

Comment: in CPanel for my hosting in MySqlDatabases, I associated the user to the database.